# A script in Tensorflow (1.4.0) needs to import 'reader.py' (which is also located in tensorflow) but fails. Not sure what to do about this

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

Preface: I am using Python 3.6.5, Tensorflow 1.4.0, and Unity Ml-Agents v0.3

I am using tensorflow(1.4.0) along with the Unity Ml-Agents git repository. In tensorflow there is a file called saved_model_utils.py that needs to import reader.py from a different file directory within the tensorflow package. My issue is that when I run the training program it fails at the import line in saved_model_utils.py. I have tried multiple different ways of specifying a direct path to file for the import but none of them satisfied the issue. I assume there is something I don't know that is making this difficult because it doesn't make sense that tensorflow would put a faulty script in there package. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a picture of the saved_model_utils.py:
[saved_model_utils.py with reader.py highlighted in the project window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6JNe.png)

Here is a picture of the terminal and error when I run the scripts:
[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqLn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the file paths, it seems like there's inconsistency in the folder names. I tried

```
from tensorflow.contrib.saved_model.python.saved_model import reader
```

and it's working. If you look at the file path in your first image, it's "saved_model" rather than "saved_models".

Hope this can fix your problem.

Comment: Wow... I feel stupid... Thanks though man! Sometimes you're too close to see the obvious problem.